# Speed up NumPy loop on 2D arrays - removes rows that are similar

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to significantly speed up the following code but to no avail. The code takes in a 2D array and removes rows of the array that, when compared to other rows in the array, are too similar. Please see below code and comments.

```
as0 = a.shape[0]
for i in range(as0):
    a2s0 = a.shape[0] # shape may change after each iteration
    if i > (a2s0 - 1):
        break
    # takes the difference between all rows in array by iterating over each
    # row. Then sums the absolutes. The condition finally gives a boolean
    # array output - similarity condition of 0.01
    t = np.sum(np.absolute(a[i,:] - a), axis=1)<0.01
    # Retains the indices that are too similar and then deletes the
    # necessary row
    inddel = np.where(t)[0]
    inddel = [k for k in inddel if k != i]
    a = np.delete(a, inddel, 0)
```

I was wondering if vectorization was possible but I'm not too familiar with it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

```
    if i >= (a2s0 - 1): # Added equality sign
        break
    # Now this only calculates over rows that have not been compared.
    t = np.sum(np.absolute(a[i,:] - a[np.arange(i+1,a2s0),:]), axis=1)>0.01
    t = np.concatenate((np.ones(i+1,dtype=bool), t))
    a = a[t, :]
```

Comment: Let's say we have row numbers : `6,10,12` "similar" to each other. So, would it be okay to remove the first two rows and keep the last one, that is `12`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't really matter which indices are removed. As long as the unique row remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1 : Broadcasting**

Here's one vectorized approach making use of [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) upon extending `a` to `3D` and then performing those computations across all iterations in a vectorized manner -

```
mask = (np.absolute(a[:,None] - a)).sum(2) < 0.01
a_out = a[~np.triu(mask,1).any(0)]
```

**Approach #2 : Using pdist('cityblock')**

For large arrays, we would run into memory issues with the previous approach. So, as another method, we could make use of pdist's `'cityblock'` that computes the manhattan distances and then ID the corresponding `row/col` in its squared distance matrix form without actually computing that form by using `searchsorted` instead for an efficient solution to it.

Here's the implementation -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

n = a.shape[0]
dists = pdist(a, 'cityblock')
idx = np.flatnonzero(dists < thresh)
sep_idx = np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum()
rm_idx = np.unique(np.searchsorted(sep_idx,idx,'right'))
a_out = np.delete(a,rm_idx,axis=0)
```

### Benchmarking

Approaches -

```
# Approach#2 from this post
def remove_similar_rows(a, thresh=0.01):
    n = a.shape[0]
    dists = pdist(a, 'cityblock')
    idx = np.flatnonzero(dists < thresh)
    sep_idx = np.arange(n-1,0,-1).cumsum()
    rm_idx = np.unique(np.searchsorted(sep_idx,idx,'right'))
    return np.delete(a,rm_idx,axis=0)

# @John Zwinck's soln
def pairwise_manhattan_distances(a, thresh=0.01):
    d = manhattan_distances(a)
    return a[~np.any(np.tril(d < thresh), axis=0)]
```

Timings -

```
In [209]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(4000,30))

# Let's set 100 rows randomly as dups    
In [210]: idx0 = np.random.choice(4000,size=100, replace=0)

In [211]: idx1 = np.random.choice(4000,size=100, replace=0)

In [217]: a[idx0] = a[idx1]

In [238]: %timeit pairwise_manhattan_distances(a, thresh=0.01)
1 loops, best of 3: 225 ms per loop

In [239]: %timeit remove_similar_rows(a, thresh=0.01)
10 loops, best of 3: 100 ms per loop
```

Comment: Your `(np.absolute(a[:,None] - a)).sum(2)` is mathematically elegant, but it blows up if the input is even moderately large.  I tried with an input shape of (4000,30) and it took many seconds, lots of memory, and then I killed it.  The `manhattan_distances(a)` in my answer does the same thing in 150 ms.  Your way is faster if the input is tiny though.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Could you share your benchmarking setup in your post?

Comment: It's simple: `a = np.random.random((4000,30))` then `%timeit (np.absolute(a[:,None] - a)).sum(2)` in IPython.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Added another efficient method, alongwith timing tests.

Comment: @JohnZwinck and Divakar, Both approaches are great! my problem however is that I start getting memory errors once the array sizes get up to (300000,1000). A less memory intensive operation would be much appreciated. I'm willing to accept a few hours of runtime (not days like my code above)

Comment: @Jean-MichelLaurenceNairac: Just run it repeatedly in a few chunks.  For example run the algorithm on the first 10k rows, then the next 10k rows, removing as you go.  Hopefully you remove lots of rows and by the end you can assemble the remaining rows for one final pass.

Answer (score 4):

Let's create some fake data:

```
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.random((4,3))
```

Now we have:

```
array([[ 0.5488135 ,  0.71518937,  0.60276338],
       [ 0.54488318,  0.4236548 ,  0.64589411],
       [ 0.43758721,  0.891773  ,  0.96366276],
       [ 0.38344152,  0.79172504,  0.52889492]])
```

Next, we want the sum of elementwise differences for all pairs of rows.  We can use [Manhattan Distance](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances.html#sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances):

```
d = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances(a)
```

Which gives:

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.33859562,  0.64870931,  0.31577611],
       [ 0.33859562,  0.        ,  0.89318282,  0.6465111 ],
       [ 0.64870931,  0.89318282,  0.        ,  0.5889615 ],
       [ 0.31577611,  0.6465111 ,  0.5889615 ,  0.        ]])
```

Now you can apply a threshold, keeping only one triangle:

```
m = np.tril(d < 0.4, -1) # large threshold just for this example
```

And get a boolean mask:

```
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Which tells you that row 0 is "too similar" to both row 1 and row 3.  Now you can remove rows from the original matrix where any element of the mask is True:

```
a[~np.any(m, axis=0)] # axis can be either 0 or 1 - design choice
```

Which gives you:

```
array([[ 0.54488318,  0.4236548 ,  0.64589411],
       [ 0.43758721,  0.891773  ,  0.96366276],
       [ 0.38344152,  0.79172504,  0.52889492]])
```

Putting it all together:

```
d = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances(a)
a = a[~np.any(np.tril(d < 0.4, -1), axis=0)]
```

Comment: To replicate yours I had to make a small change: `m = np.tril(d < 0.4, k = -1)`

Comment: @Jean-MichelLaurenceNairac: You're right, I neglected to set `k=-1` in my posted code.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

First the line:

```
t = np.sum(np.absolute(a[i,:] - a), axis=1)<0.01
```

is taking the sum of the absolute value of the difference between a single line the and the whole array every time. This is probably not what you would need, try instead taking the differences between the current line and the lines later in the array. *You have already compared all of the preceding lines with the current so why do it again?*

Also deleting lines from the array is an expensive, slow operation, so you will probably find it quicker to check all of the lines and then delete the  near duplicates.  You could also not check any lines that already slated for deletion as you know that they will be removed.

Comment: Thank you Steve. Thus far I've added an edit which removes the delete

Comment: I have now included code that only calculates over rows that have not been seen. Thanks again